# IIS Rewrite or Redirect?

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I host a web service on "http://myIpAddress:82/". I have the same web application on "http://myIpAddress/myWay/" too.

For unmanagable network reasons, I need to redirect the first address to second one, with all subdirectories.

When I write a redirect rule on IIS it works on browsers, but not on "postman" or on my real rest clients"

How can I handle this situation? Should I redirect and add some extra settings? or rewrite the url some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the requests from "postman" and your rest clients get request or something else (post, put etc)? If not get requests then they will probably get redirected as a get request and lose post data. If your issue is related to post data then you might be able to do something like [this](http://chandermani.blogspot.com/2013/05/iis-url-rewrite-and-http-post-data.html)